# Duplicate Button Baseline from Material UI in header

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

- @material-ui/core - 4.3.1
- react - 16.8.6/16.9.0
- webpack - 4.38.0/4.39.1

In our project when we have a material ui button in one component, then in a separate component on the same page we use an expansion panel or another type of button we have a second instance of MuiButtonBase imported into the header. This is causing our custom styles to be overwritten and styles to be dumped all together.

We've followed the steps from https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page

We've also tried the steps found on https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15610

Neither of these has fixed this for us. :(

```
 splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minChunks: 2,
      name: 'vendor',
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
        },
      }
    },
  },
```

```
import {
  Modal, Button,
} from '@material-ui/core';

() => (
  <Modal open={open}>
          <Button className={classes.cancel} onClick={onCancel}>{cancelText}</Button>
          <Button className={classes.delete} onClick={onConfirm}>{confirmText}</Button>
  </Modal>
);
```

```
import {
  ExpansionPanel, ExpansionPanelSummary, ExpansionPanelDetails,
} from '@material-ui/core';

() => (
<ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary onClick={toggle} className={classes.summary} expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}>
          <span>
            {name}
          </span>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          {children}
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
);
```

It'd be great if we didn't have two MuiButtonBases causing our styles to be overridden.

[image]

Comment: It's dumb I can't post the image... I had to just put the link. Sorry everyone. :(

Comment: Have you tried giving the buttons unique ids or classNames?

Comment: @TechTeam12 you can also just paste the html into your post and indicate the duplicate elements.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart The html is in the screen shot. The header gets the style injected twice. If you ran a MUI project with two components on page that each did something like the snippets above you should get it.

Sorry, if it's snide just not sure what you're looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TechTeam12 I meant paste the html into your post instead of screenshotting it.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart new to getting help. What html is relevant? There is a ton of stuff being generated as html by MUI. Not sure what would help out here.

Comment: @TechTeam12 put the content of your screenshot into your post as text.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Is there something specifically you're looking for that isn't in the image? There is a TON of text generated and copying it has like 2,000 lines.

Comment: @cullanrocks MUI styles will give them unique style names. In the project we're not using ids. So, not sure that should/is an issue?

Comment: @TechTeam12 *the content of your screenshot* basically take the text you screenshotted and paste it *and only that text*. You don't need the entire 2000 lines

Comment: I'll see if I can't get it. What're you looking for? I'd love to be able to identify it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The issue was that I was using `@material-ui/core` as a declared plugin in the babel file....

This was a mistake. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: hi there, I have the same issue, could you tell me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I searched a lot and what fixed it for me was that I changed all imports from `@material-ui/core` to `@mui/material`.

Side note: Also not listed, but just wanted to say that the cache rtl and ltr needed to be present on the topest component, and mui recognizes by html dir attribute.